# Jquery Hover change image and show box

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of images lined up that I want to on hover show a different image and add a box. I found a post on stack that helped me to do the first part but I am unsure how I should implement the part of showing the box. I am thinking that I would have to some how animate the opacity from 0 to 100 on the hover over and then back on the hover out but again I am not sure how to implement this. Any ideas?

My code so far:

HTML

```
<article class="homeFeatured">
    <section>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url($perm->category . '/' . $perm->perm_name) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/products/' . $perm->perm_name ?>" alt="" />
            <span>View Item</span>
        </a>    
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url($perm->category . '/' . $perm->perm_name) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/products/' . $perm->perm_name ?>" alt="" />
            <span>View Item</span>
        </a>    
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url($perm->category . '/' . $perm->perm_name) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('public/img/products/' . $perm->perm_name ?>" alt="" />
            <span>View Item</span>
        </a>    
    </section>
</article​​​​​​​​>​
```

CSS:

```
.homeFeatured section{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 303px;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.homeFeatured span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #8cc63f;
    border: 1px solid #638d2b;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".homeFeatured img")
           .mouseover(function() { 
               var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "Hover.jpg";
               $(this).attr("src", src); 
           })
           .mouseout(function() {
               var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("Hover", "");
               $(this).attr("src", src);
});​
```

​

Comment: Is the `<span>` what you want to show on hover?

Comment: yes that is what I want to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

- [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFNc6/1/)
- [Working fiddle, CSS3 only](http://jsfiddle.net/6pSpt/1/)

---

Assuming you want to display the `<span>` on hover, there's two options:

Depending on the browsers you need to cover, using jQuery for the animation might be a bit of an overkill.

If you can live with IE < 10 not actually *animating* the transition, the CSS solution will do.

Pure CSS:

```
.homeFeatured span {
    /* ... the stuff you have already */
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
}

.homeFeatured section a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Keep in mind that the IE-proprietary `filter` properties will invalidate your CSS.

jQuery:

```
 $(".homeFeatured img")
       .mouseover(function() { 
           var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "Hover.jpg";
           $(this).attr("src", src);
           $('+ span', this).animate({opacity : 1});
       })
       .mouseout(function() {
           var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("Hover", "");
           $(this).attr("src", src);
           $('+ span', this).animate({opacity : 0});
});​
```

Comment: ok this might be a stupid question but wouldnt the `'+ span', this` look for `.homeFeatured img span`?

Comment: Nope, take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFNc6/) ;) – the `+` in the selector essentially means "immediate sibling".